# Php storm filewatcher minify whole directory

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, yui

I've successfully setup my YUI Compressor JS. But it doesn't works like I would like it to.

I would like it to minify an entire directory every time a file in that directory gets changed.

So far I've made a scope with the directory, but the compressor only works on the file I have changed (in the scope), and not on the entire directory. So it only minify's that one file, and not the entire directory.

Comment: Well .. then you have to list (hard code) all files that needs to be minified in one go (that's if your minifier supports lists). Or maybe it supports folder names (even easier: point to a folder and it will do all files in it)? If your minifier does not support that (or you want dynamic/advanced stuff) then look at build tools like gulp/grunt which can list all files in specified folder: create a task that will be doing such job and then use it in File Watcher.

Comment: Hi, I solved it by using gulp and setting it up accordingly! Thank you so much for your answer! I'm gonna markt this as solved!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by using gulp and setting it up accordingly. All I have to do then is running gulp and everything works.